quarkus opentelemetry not propagating the traces to the smallrye-messaging consumer of another quarkus microserice
I have 2 quarkus applications, microserviceA, microservieB.
having below dependency with other required dependencies in both the services,
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka:3.9.5'
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-extension-trace-propagators'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-opentelemetry'

microserviceA has a consumer. This consumer does some grpc calls, http call  and add data to database and then produces message to another topic, which is consumed by  microservieB.
Here I loose the traces on microservieB, It create a new trace.
According to this doc https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry in quarkus-messaging kafka section I am manually passing the context to the consumer from the producer still no luck.
It is mentioned in the one of comment of a github issue as well to pass the context manually (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/26353)
On Jaeger monitoring tool, It creates different trace for consumer in  microservieB.
As i mentioned earlier In microserviceA, I have a consumer. This consumer does some grpc calls, http call  and add data to database and then produces message to another topic for microserviceB to consume. So the database calls and the producing to kafka doesn't depend on each other so putting the producing part in async call, see below.
   @Channel("data-updates-out")
   Emitter<DataResponse> kafkaEmitter;
   
  public void publishToKafka(String id, List<Data> data) {

    Log.infof("Producing data for id: %s, %s", id, data);
    OutgoingKafkaRecordMetadata<String> stringOutgoingKafkaRecordMetadataBuilder =
            OutgoingKafkaRecordMetadata.<String>builder().withKey(id).build();
    TracingMetadata tm = TracingMetadata.withCurrent(Context.current());
    DataResponse response = GetMarketOddsResponse.newBuilder().addData(data).build();
    Message<DataResponse> message =
            Message.of(response, Metadata.of(stringOutgoingKafkaRecordMetadataBuilder, tm));

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> kafkaEmitter.send(message));
}

At consumer side in microserviceB, I am checking the context and attaching it.
@Incoming("data-updates-in")
@Acknowledgment(Acknowledgment.Strategy.PRE_PROCESSING)
public CompletionStage<Void> consumerData(Message<DataResponse> message) {
    marketOddsResponseMessage.getMetadata(TracingMetadata.class).ifPresent(metadata -> {
        Log.infof("tracing context" + metadata.getCurrentContext());
        QuarkusContextStorage.INSTANCE.attach(metadata.getCurrentContext());
    });
    Log.infof("Received data event with value : %s", message.getPayload());
    return message.ack();
}

None of the above worked, So I tried adding below dependency. That didn't work as well.
implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-extension-trace-propagators").

NOTE: quarkus version : 3.9.2, quarkus-opentelemetry : 3.9.2
This is kind of log I get when producing message from microserviceA.
2024-05-02T12:49:20.082Z INFO  traceId= parentId=, spanId=, sampled= [co.sp.pr.XProducer] (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3) Producing message
   

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong??

You don't need opentelemetry-extension-trace-propagators.
Can you please post a sample with the method signature and used annotations for the producer and consumer parts?

@BrunoBaptista updated the question with code snippet.

Looking at the examples and log at the end, you seem like calling the publishToKafka method on the fork-join pool, maybe on a parallel stream? The Quarkus opentelemetry context propagation does not work on the fork-join pool. So even if you manually add the TracingMetadata, you probably do not have an active trace. If you can provide a more complete example we can provide more guidance.

It would be really interesting to see where the log Producing message is coming from. I know I hand-rolled some propagation in the past by manually propagating the context (github.com). But this needs an active opentelementry context.

@OzanGünalp You are right , i am producing the message like, CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> kafkaEmitter.send(message)); I have updated the  question as well, In microserviceA I am consuming a topic from other serviceC ---> save data to db ---> publish to kafka. Is there a way to see distributed tracing in this kind of scenario???
And let's say I have to make multiple call independent of each other then I will use parallelstream, so there is no way to get same trace id????

The kafkaEmitter.send call is already async so you do not need to wrap it with CompletableFuture.runAsync. If you delegate calls to forkjoin pool there is no way the context propagation can follow that. If you need more control over the async send operations, you can check replacing Emitter with MutinyEmitter.

CompletableFuture creates a different thread, opentelemetry doesn't pass context to new thread out of the box, So Pass the context manually to a different thread. Look at the below example.
    Context currentContext = Context.current();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try (Scope scope = currentContext.makeCurrent()) {
            publishStateToKafka(xState);
        }
    });

